# Wordpress background image when I click on a button

Tags: wordpress, image

I have a little question for my Wordpress page. Is there any possibility to change the background image on the landing page when I click on a button in my navigation bar? The button lets me already  back to the landing page when it´s clicked.

I tried to find any plugins for my problem, but found nothing.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) . As you're new, please take the [tour] and read [ask] too, to understand how to get the best out of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You would use JavaScript to change a background image on click; would be something like this (untested):

```html
<div id=“background-element”></div>
<button id=“clicked-button”>Click me to change the background</button>

<script>
document.addEventListener( ‘click’, function ( ev ) {
    if ( ! ev.target.matches( ‘#clicked-button’ ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    // Prevent processing the button’s default behavior.
    ev.preventDefault();

    document.querySelector( ‘#background-element’ ).style.backgroundImage = ‘https://example.com/background.jpg’;
} );
```